container not aligned properly and images not appearing correctly
i am trying to make a web page look like my canva design below but i got the second image beneath that as my result.
My Canva design
My result


.about-us-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: none;
}

.about-image {
    object-fit: contain;
}

.about-us-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
 }
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div class="about-us-image">
        <img class="about-image"
        src="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/templatemo_591_villa_agency/assets/images/smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device.jpg"
         alt="smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div class="about-us-text">
        <h2><h2 style="color: #56aeff;">Who We Are</h2>
        <p>With more than a decade of experience, we are a trusted team of business and financial planners to help you start your business or retirement in Bali, Indonesia and other islands</p>
    </div>
</div>



if you want to view the full code, it's on my codepen
i tried adding modifying my css attributre for the container to have no background image and no background color to allow the original background image from my external css to appear but iyt has not worked. i also tried adding the attribute of object fit to contain for my image class but it hasn't worked.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

First please put your code through a validator. You appear to have a spurious 

Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see why the img isn't loading for example?

use the background: url property.
for example
|
Background: URL('link.png'); //image link past here 

and set this property in .about-us-image

There were several factors affecting the output, so I made some changes to achieve the desired layout. Here's the updated result:

Changes Made:
1. Images: I used direct links to images to demonstrate the layout properly.
2. Body Style: I added styles to the body element to cover the entire screen background.
3. Flexbox and Background Properties: I used CSS flex properties and background properties to adjust the whole layout.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/templatemo_591_villa_agency/styles.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body {
        background-image: url('https://i.pngimg.me/image_by_url?url=https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/network-connections-background_1048-8245.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .data-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      .about-us-image {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
      }

      .about-image {
        height: 500px;
        width: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .about-us-text {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 100px;
        width: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="data-container">
      <div class="about-us-image">
        <img
          class="about-image"
          src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device_1262-5773.jpg"
          alt="smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="about-us-text">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 60px; color: #56aeff; margin: 0;">Who We Are</p>
        <p style="font-size: 18px;">
          With more than a decade of experience, we are a trusted team of
          business and financial planners to help you start your business or
          retirement in Bali, Indonesia and other islands
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

NOTE: For the better understanding of Flexbox, please check out this Flexbox guide.

Was it necessary to change the semantics (removing the h2)?

@AHaworth no, it wasn't necessary. I preferred to use p or span when I have to add custom CSS, so I did.

I appreciate that the visual effect can be the same, but remember that semantics may be important for aiding accessibility.

@MuhammadAleem thanks for the answer,it worked but the text is a bit further apart from the image and a bit too far in the middle, how do I bring it close to the image to the left but a bit upwards to the top level of the image?  will margin-left: 30 px work?

@Samuel if you wanna adjust text layout then you will need to make following changes in .about-us-text: (1) Add following property align-self: start; (2) Change padding to padding: 80px 50px 0 0;.

@MuhammadAleem thank you for the input. I just applied what you said but it does not affect the text alignment and it's still a bit further out to the right from the image and it still has not aligned to the top of the text container. can you check if this is correct? https://hastebin.skyra.pw/elomezetab.css

@Samuel No, there is some misunderstanding, I asked you to add following padding padding: 80px 50px 0 0 instead of padding: 80px 50px;. And keep rest of the CSS which I have posted.

@MuhammadAleem is this the proper css attribute you mean? https://hastebin.skyra.pw/vopozujoca.css  it has moved the text slightly upwards but not in the same level as the top of the image and there is still a wide gap between thew text and image

@Samuel Please check the Flexbox guide which I have provided in my response. And check this guide to learn about padding in css. Make adjustments and then you will be able to fix these issues.

@MuhammadAleem i have read flexbox guide and have already implemented it and it moved the text closer to the left but still too much spacing on the left  between text and image and text is not on the same level as image perhaps you can correct my errors. this is my code: https://codepen.io/Samuel-Christian-the-looper/pen/poXeQmX
